# Restart casper script on phantom crash

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have a script that crashes after a while. It says: `PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide...` Is it possible to restart the script when such a crash happens? I use Windows task scheduler to run the casperjs script.

Best Regards